# why do we have to simplify the division before calculating limit?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Why do we have to simplify the division before calculating limit $?$. For example:
$$
\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^{2} - 1}{x - 1}
$$

and $\lim_{x \to 1}\left(x + 1\right)$.

Comment: Please don't use links to images—that's a barrier to searches and to people using screen readers.

Comment: i am not allowed to put it directly

Comment: I hope the question is simple

Comment: Please take the effort to type all necessary information into the post itself, which you are allowed to do. If you want volunteers to spend their energy helping you, please be willing to spend some energy yourself.

Comment: Just a little hint: $\frac{0}{0}$ is an indeterminate form, right?

Comment: How might you proceed instead, if you were to avoid simplifying the fraction?

Comment: You don't have to, it just makes things much much easier.

Comment: Feel free to solve it not simplifying the fraction.

Comment: In fact you **can** solve it without simplifying the fraction. So you **do not** have to simplify the fraction. It just happens to be very simple and easy to do that way, and it is good for you to know the simple ways of solving problems.

Answer (score 1):

The *point* of the limit is to *allow* you to simplify it in the first place.  Without the limit, you can't actually do the simplification, because it is a divide-by-zero.  The limit allows doing the simplification in a way that is still legal.

Comment: You could also assert $x\neq 1$, cancel $x-1$, and not have to deal with limits at all. Limits have other uses, such as showing that a discontinuity is removable.

Comment: @DavidK You can't simultaneously assert that $x \neq 1$ and find the value at $x = 1$.

Comment: You can't find the value at $x=1,$ period. That's not what a limit does. The way the limit allows you to simplify the expression is precisely because during the evaluation of the limit it is given that $x\neq 1.$ But you can also have $x\neq 1$ in a context that isn't evaluating a limit.